# In middleman, how do set variables?

Tags: ruby, middleman

I've started experimenting with middleman and ruby.

The sample layout has this string:

```
<body class="<%= page_classes %>
```

On any given page, how do I set the 'page_class'?

Comment: I'm not sure about middleman specifically, but I'm going to hazard an educated guess that `page_classes` is nit a variable, but is actually a method.

Answer (score 3):

`<%= page_classes %>` is one of Middleman's default view helpers and returns a string based upon the current page's filename and directory, e. g.

- for `/index.html` it returns `index`
- for `/folder1/index.html` it returns `folder1 folder1_index`
- for `/folder1/folder2/page.html` it returns `folder1 folder1_folder2 folder1_folder2_page`

and so on (above examples are adapted from [Middleman's Relish documentation for 'page_classes'](https://www.relishapp.com/middleman/middleman-core/docs/built-in-page-classes-view-helper)).

Using the snippet from the sample layout like you posted, you could style your pages or [highlight the corresponding navigation item via CSS](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css).

*Edit:* To add even more options to the answers provided by Marek, you could use

- "[Local YAML Data](http://middlemanapp.com/metadata/local-data/)" or
- "[Individual Page Configuration (YAML Frontmatter)](http://middlemanapp.com/metadata/yaml-frontmatter/)"

both of which are described on Middleman's website/documentation.
Note that variables set via YAML Frontmatter also become available in your [layouts](http://middlemanapp.com/templates/templates-layouts-partials/).

Answer (score 1):

You can define variable in config.rb with the @ symbol such as:

```
@var = ["something", "here", ...]
```

and make it visible to templates by adding, in config.rb:

```
set :var, @var
```

if it's a method instead, you should just define it under the helper section of config.rb.

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable in config.rb

```
set :var, ["something", "here"]
```

In your template you will have available

```
config[:var]
```